# Chrome - allowing access to webcam

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, camera

I'm playing around with javascript on my site and had an idea involving webcams. My first order of business is to simply grab data from the users' webcam and show it on the site.

My site is [hheim.com](http://hheim.com/selfie).
Here's all the code:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Selfie</title>
</head>
<body>
<video></video>
<script src="video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

video.js

```
(function () {
navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||             navigator.mozGetUserMedia);
navigator.getMedia(
{video:true, audio:false},
function (mediaStream) {
var video = document.getElemtsByTagName('video')[0];
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
video.play();
},
function (error) {
console.log(error);
})
})();
```

When I load the page, Chrome says it's blocking the webcam. OK, I expected that. Working as intended. However, when I click the camera icon to unblock for my site, the only two options are "Ask" and "Continue Blocking." It defaults to "Continue Blocking".

When I change to "Ask" a toolbar drops down prompting me to reload the page. When I reload the page, I'm not asked, it's still blocked, and it still defaults to "Continue Blocking."

I've done some Googling and can't seem to find a solution. Is there more code I need to include? Am I the one with a problem here (cookies, etc)? Or is this an actual problem with Chrome?

Comment: `document.getElemtsByTagName('video')[0];`?, revise that syntax.

Comment: I guess you are running your page on HTTP, right? Browsers are much more tolerant when you use HTTPS. Chrome even remembers the answer and then does not ask second time...

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check if user media available and ready to be granted. And remember eval is evil :)

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia (

      // constraints
      {
         video: true,
         audio: true
      },

      // successCallback
      function(localMediaStream) {
         var video = document.getElementById('stream');
         video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
         // Do something with the video here, e.g. video.play()
      },

      // errorCallback
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia

Set id for video and autoplay attribute;

```
<video id="stream" autoplay></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to go into my Chrome settings and change the default webcam setting from "Deny" to "Ask".

One would think Chrome could remember my decision for the page when it asks me to reload it, but I guess not.

Thanks for the replies anyways!